# Codigo php no funciona en un unico archivo, solo funciona cuando los separo

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Tengo un problema con php:

Primero os pasare mi php que lista una lista de compras a partir de una tabla de una base datos:

```
<?php include_once("read_BD.php");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM lista_de_compra";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$rows = $result->fetch_All(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Código Lista</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Descripcion</th>
                <th>Precio</th>
                <th colspan="2">Acciones</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach($rows as $row){ ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row["cod_lista"] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["Nombre"] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["Descripcion"] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row["Precio"] ?></td>
                    <td><a class="button" href="<?php echo "update_bd.php?id=" . $row["cod_lista"]?>">Editar</a></td>
                    <td><a class="button" href="<?php echo "delete_bd.php?ids=" . $row["cod_lista"]?>">Eliminar</a></td>
                </tr>
                <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="6"><a href="">Boton</a></th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
      </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Estoy haciendo un CRUD y estoy atascado en el update. Este es mi codigo php del update que primero obtiene los datos de la row a partir del php de arriba:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_GET["id"])) exit();
$id = $_GET["id"];
include_once ("read_BD.php");
$sentencia = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM lista_de_compra WHERE cod_lista = ?");
$sentencia->execute([$id]);
$resultado=$sentencia->get_result();
$lista = $resultado->fetch_assoc();
if($lista === FALSE){
    #No existe
    echo "¡No existe alguna persona con ese ID!";
    exit();
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Formulario para rellenar la lista:</legend>
            <input type="hidden" name="codigo" value="<?php echo $lista["cod_lista"] ?>">
            <label for="fname">Nombre:</label><br>
            <input value="<?php echo $lista["Nombre"] ?>" type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
            <label for="message">Descripcion:</label><br>
            <textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="30"  id="message"><?php echo $lista["Descripcion"] ?></textarea><br><br>
            <label for="price">Precio:</label><br>
            <input value="<?php echo $lista["Precio"] ?>" type="number" id="price" name="price" min="0" ><br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </fieldset>
    </form>

</body>
</html>

<?php
#Salir si alguno de los datos no está presente
if(
    !isset($_POST["fname"]) || 
    !isset($_POST["message"]) || 
    !isset($_POST["price"]) ||
    !isset($_POST["codigo"])
) exit();

#Si todo va bien, se ejecuta esta parte del código...

$codigo = $_POST["codigo"];
$fname = $_POST["fname"];
$message = $_POST["message"];
$price = $_POST["price"];


$sentencia_update = $conn->prepare("UPDATE lista_de_compra SET Nombre = ?, Descripcion = ?, Precio = ? WHERE cod_lista = ?");
$resultado_update = $sentencia_update->execute([$fname, $message, $price, $codigo]); # Pasar en el mismo orden de los ?
if($resultado_update === TRUE) echo "Cambios guardados";
else echo "Algo salió mal. Por favor verifica que la tabla exista, así como el ID del usuario";
?>
```

Esta parte funciona y muestra en el formulario html los datos que quiero modificar:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_GET["id"])) exit();
$id = $_GET["id"];
include_once ("read_BD.php");
$sentencia = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM lista_de_compra WHERE cod_lista = ?");
$sentencia->execute([$id]);
$resultado=$sentencia->get_result();
$lista = $resultado->fetch_assoc();
if($lista === FALSE){
    #No existe
    echo "¡No existe alguna persona con ese ID!";
    exit();
}
?>
```

El problema esta en esta parte del php:

```
<?php
#Salir si alguno de los datos no está presente
if(
    !isset($_POST["fname"]) || 
    !isset($_POST["message"]) || 
    !isset($_POST["price"]) ||
    !isset($_POST["codigo"])
) exit();

#Si todo va bien, se ejecuta esta parte del código...

$codigo = $_POST["codigo"];
$fname = $_POST["fname"];
$message = $_POST["message"];
$price = $_POST["price"];


$sentencia_update = $conn->prepare("UPDATE lista_de_compra SET Nombre = ?, Descripcion = ?, Precio = ? WHERE cod_lista = ?");
$resultado_update = $sentencia_update->execute([$fname, $message, $price, $codigo]); # Pasar en el mismo orden de los ?
if($resultado_update === TRUE) echo "Cambios guardados";
else echo "Algo salió mal. Por favor verifica que la tabla exista, así como el ID del usuario";
?>
```

Sencillamente no coge los valores submit modificados y se queda en una pantalla en blanco.

Este código funciona ya que intente hacer el update con ese codigo en un archivo php aparte redirigiendolo en action con la ruta en vez de php_self. Asi funciono.
Pero a mi me interesa hacerlo todo en un unico php y no en dos.
¿Que se tendría que modificar para hacerlo todo en un mismo php? ¿Que estoy haciendo mal?

Esto es lo que sale en el HTML utilizando las variables var_dump($_GET) y var_dump($_POST) cuando escojo modificar la primera lista de compra:

Cuando esta el html: **array(1) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" } array(0) { }**

Esto es lo que sale cuando envio los datos modificados con el submit:

**array(0) { } array(4) { ["codigo"]=> string(1) "1" ["fname"]=> string(7) "Huevosj" ["message"]=> string(20) "Esto es una prueba ." ["price"]=> string(1) "8" }**

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Depura tu código, por ejemplo poniendo en la primera fila del archivo PHP esto: `var_dump($_GET);` Además, explica cómo estás mandando los datos al archivo que debería hacer el UPDATE. Veo que tienes esto al principio: `if(!isset($_GET["id"])) exit();` Y en el formulario no veo que tengas nada con un `name="id"`. Los formularios se serializan usando como clave el valor de la etiqueta `name` de los elementos, por lo que puede que no esté recibiendo nada en `$_GET["id"]`. Cuando algo no funciona, depura eso que no funciona usando `var_dump`.

Comment: Buenas, el problema está en la línea que indica A.Cedano. Cuando haces el POST del formulario no vas a recibir nada en $_GET. Al no recibir nada se ejecuta el exit. Tienes que cambiar esa parte, pero para tenerlo "unificado" deberías mandar siempre por uno y otro método el id, para identificar el registro que quieres mostrar (GET - RETRIEVE) o actualizar (POST - UPDATE), si el id te viene por POST, actualiza y recupera los datos; si te viene el id en el GET recupera los datos.

Comment: El ***if(!isset($_GET["id"])) exit();*** hace referencia a la id de mi tabla que obtengo de otro php. He editado mi post para incluir ese php. Como he dicho la primera parte de mi php funciona y se muestran los datos que puedo modificar. El problema es el php de abajo se queda en blanco y no se hace el update. @A.Cedano

Comment: La primera parte mi update_bd.php muestra los datos que se pueden modificar en un formulario y la  parte de abajo del php en teoria deberia poder obtener la modificación y aplicarla en un update. No lo hace @A.Cedano

Comment: ¿Pusiste el `var_dump` como te dije? ¿Muestra algo? Pon dos: `var_dump($_GET);` y `var_dump($_POST);` y dinos qué muestra. Y mientras más claridad mejor. En vez de hablarnos de *parte de abajo*  y *parte de arriba*  dinos: *esto no funciona* y pon el código a continuación.

Comment: Por ejemplo, ¿cómo se llama el archivo del último fragmento de código en la pregunta? ¿Ese archivo es `update_bd.php`? Si lo es, ¿por qué haces en ese archivo un `SELECT * FROM lista_de_compra WHERE cod_lista = ?`, cuando puedes hacer un `UPDATE FROM laTabla SET = .... WHERE cod_lista = ?`? Es decir, no explicas con claridad las cosas y hay que ir adivinando y sacando la información a cuenta gotas. Explica qué es cada cosa claramente y dinos el resultado de las depuraciones hechas con `var_dump`. Si aprendes a depurar el código te ahorrarás horas.

Comment: He modificado mi pregunta, espero que haya mas claridad .Y hago un select **SELECT * FROM lista_de_compra WHERE cod_lista = ?** para que me muestre visualmente en el formulario html los datos de la fila que intenta modificarse.  Y a partir de ahi cambiarla a tu gusto agregándole cosas o eliminandolas. @A.Cedano

Comment: Creo que no entiendes bien como se evalua un fichero PHP. A ver, la primera vez que llamas a tu fichero update_db.php lo haces con un GET, de forma que te pinta el formulario. La parte de abajo no se ejecuta completa por que haces un exit al no tener nada en $_POST. Cuando envías el formulario se vuelve a pedir la misma página entera, no es que se ejecute la parte de abajo, se vuelve a evaluar desde el principio y como no es un GET, no tienes nada en $_GET, se ejecuta el exit (se queda en blanco) en la línea que te hemos indicado.

Comment: Si quieres usar la misma página para seleccionar los datos y también actualizarlos, tienes que poner todo el código arriba y distinguir ahí entre GET y POST.

Comment: Ahora ya os entiendo. Y comprendo porque mi código se comporta de la forma en que lo hace. Tendré que distinguir como dice @RubioRic aunque no se  como comenzar.

Comment: La idea es la que te comentaba antes: si viene el id en el GET solo quieres mostrar los datos, si viene en el POST (inclúyelo como un hidden input en el formulario) es que quieres actualizarlos y luego mostrarlos. Como ves siempre se muestran, eso ya lo tienes hecho, es poner un if más que actualice antes de mostrar. La misma condición de ese if puedes usarla para mostrar un mensaje adicional indicando que los datos se han actualizado correctamente.

Comment: Otro problema que yo veo (y por eso te preguntaba por el `SELECT`) es que aplicas una especie de lógica inversa, haciendo trabajar doblemente al código. Me refiero a que haces un `SELECT` allí donde pones el botón `update` y al presionar en el botón, haces de nuevo el mismo `SELECT` para traer **de nuevo** el dato que ya tenías o debías tener al presionar el botón. Esto además es pésimo desde el punto de vista de la experiencia de usuario. Es mejor mostrar los datos ahí, donde tienes el botón, abrirlos para la edición si fuera necesario y mandar los nuevos datos ...

Comment: ... cuando presiones el botón, para hacer la actualización. No tienes que mostrarlos de entrada, los puedes dejar en atributos `data-` y mostrarlos una vez el botón sea presionado. Dicho eso, este tipo de operaciones se hacen hoy día con la ayuda de Ajax o la nueva API Fetch de Javascript. Ambas te permitirán enviar y traer cosas del servidor sin tener que recargar constantemente la página.

Comment: @A.Cedano Yo veo bien lo que indicas y tienes razón, pero ya sería una mejora en el proceso. Yo primero conseguiría que funcionara solo con PHP y luego ya aplicaría lo que tú indicas que implicaría un cambio total de enfoque usando llamadas asíncronas y javascript y dos páginas PHP (una para mostrar y otra para actualizar).

Comment: Quieres hacer todo en un solo archivo si o si?? porque si es así puedo preparar una respuesta para guarte un poco de como manejar POST y GET en un mismo archivo aunque yo preferiría que dividieras las cosas. Espero tu respuesta a este coment.

Comment: @OCHOA Quiero que todo este en la misma página. Estoy haciendo un curso de php y como trabajo tengo que hacer este CRUD y como no quiero depender de chapgpt estoy utilizando código de distintas partes aquí y alli que no comprendo al 100% como funcionan......

Comment: Pagina no es lo mismo que archivo, voy a preparar algo que te oriente por lo menos...

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: Mi respuesta es general en base a donde Sylar (buen nick por cierto) dice:

> Tendré que distinguir entre las dos formas y no se donde empezar

```php
<?php

    if ($_GET) {
        echo '<pre>';
            print_r($_GET);
        echo '</pre>';
    }

    if ($_POST) {
        echo '<pre>';
            print_r($_POST);
        echo '</pre>';
    }

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Parser</title>
</head>
<body>
    <br><br>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Nombre"><br>
        <input type="text" name="dni" placeholder="DNI"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Respuesta del navegador si no tengo nada en GET

```
Array
(
    [name] => Ochoa
    [dni] => 12345678A
)
```

Respuesta del navegador si tengo algo tanto en POST como en GET: **localhost/index.php?var=OCHOA**

```
Array
(
    [var] => OCHOA
)

Array
(
    [name] => Ochoa
    [dni] => 12345678A
)
```

A partir de ahí, tu puedes gestionar que cosas son con `GET` y que cosas son con `POST` o ambas a la vez.

Es después de cada `IF($_METHOD)` donde debes manejar si una variable esta definida y/o tiene algún valor, es ahí donde harás algún proceso (update) o mostraras algo porque cada `IF($_METHOD)` maneja los datos de forma separada. Es más esto lo hice en base a un pequeño ejercicio que resolví acá en SOes hace unos meses, luego puedo subir ese ejercicio, resuelto en un solo archivo.

Otra cosa que quiero que veas es que en el `action` del formulario, yo (repito YO) no necesito definir nada (temas de seguridad y mejores practicas luego) con dejarlo en blanco funciona para que el formulario se "envíe" a si mismo.